# How to grant all privileges on all tables to one user

Tags: sql, sql-server

recently,I need to do some database homework by SqlSever,but I only study it two days.I have a question about"grant all privileges on all tables to one user"

grant all privileges
on all tables
to uer

Comment: The problem is not clear to me. Are you struggling with restrictions and looking for instructions to become `sysadmin`, enabling you to proceed with your homework assignment without having to worry about permissions? Or are you working on proper security configuration _as part of_ an assignment, demanding you to grant permission to tables _only_ (and not to stored procedures, UDFs, views and other objects a developer might need)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either a dynammic sql to grant such privileges to only user base tables or grant specific table privilege to the all database to all kind of tables.

1 - ALL to user tables (with dynamic SQL) :

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'GRANT ALL ON [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] TO MY_USER_SQL;'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
EXEC (@SQL);
```

2 - Specific table privilege :

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES 
ON DATABASE::MY_DATABASE
TO MY_USER_SQL;
```